# Can a total rational metric space be complete?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let's call a metric space $(M,d)$ a total rational metric space if:

1. For every $x,y\in M$, $d(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}$.
2. For every $x\in M$ and every rational $q\geq0$ there exists a $y\in M$ such that $d(x,y)=q$.

Can a total rational metric space be complete?

Comment: What about the case $M=\mathbb Q $ and $d (x,y)=|x-y|$.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima but that is not complete.  We can find a Cauchy sequence converging to $\sqrt 2$

Comment: @RossMillikan yes i know. or $1+1/1+1/2!+1/3!+... $ which converges to $e $.

Comment: Edited, thanks for the comment.

Comment: I have no idea how to answer this, but as a first observation, if such an $M$ exists, then by the Baire category theorem the metric $d$ must be locally constant on an open dense subset of $M\times M$.

Comment: It can't be compact. No closed ball can be compact.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo, why are you talking about *compactness*? The question is about *completeness*. Also, you are wrong; the closed balls in $\mathbb R$ are compact.

Comment: I mean that a space that is compact plus the required properties does not exist.

Comment: I don't think that anyone has looked for a compact space. But why can't it be compact? Your argument was incorrect. The closed balls in $\mathbb R^n$ are compact.

Comment: Such a space isn't connected (pick any $x\in M$,  then $U= \{y, d(y,x) < \sqrt{2}\}$ and $V=\{y, d(x,y)>\sqrt{2}\}$ contradict connectedness). The space cannot be $\Bbb{Q}$-geodesic (I don't know if it's a standard name, but I guess you understand what I mean).

Comment: Take $x\in M$ and then $M= \cup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} \{y: d(x, y) = r\}$. So if $M$ is complete, by Baire's category theorem there exist $z \in M$, $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ so that $\{y: d(z, y) < r\} \subset \{y: d(x, y) = q\}$. Thus such $M$ cannnot be realized as a Banach space.

Comment: Suppose that a closed ball is compact, then you can take a point $x$ in the ball and a sequence of points in the ball such that the distances to $x$ converge to an irrational number, by compactness the sequence has a converging subsequence which is impossible as the distance tfrom $x$ to the limit point would be irrational. @md2perpe .

Comment: @MatsudaToyomu Can you explain the last sentence in your comment, please?

Comment: @SergioEnriqueYarzaAcuña I apologize for insufficient comment. Let $(M, \| \cdot \|)$ be a Banach space. Now suppose that the induced metric $d$ is complete and totally rational. For $y \in M$ and $a > 0$, we define $B(y, a) := \{ y' : d(y, y') < a \}$. By the above argument, there exist $z \in M$, $r > 0$, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ so that $B(z, r) \subset \{ y: d(0, y) = q\}$. By the second required property $q > 0$. Then $w := (1+\frac{r}{2q}) z \in B(z, r)$ but $\| w \| = q + \frac{r}{2} \neq q$, contradiction.

Comment: This does not answer the question.
Consider the infinite directed tree starting at a node, where each node has countably many children.Set $d(x,x) = 0$ for all nodes $x$. If there is a directed arrow from $x$ to $y$, then give that length one unique rational number in $\mathbb{Q}_{+}$. For all $z$ for which there is a path (directed or not) from $x$ to $z$, define $d(x,z)$ then recursively to be the least length path from $x$ to $z$.

This, however, is not complete since intuitively both depth-first and breadth-first searches can lead to Cauchy sequences that go nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example.  Let $M$ be the set all well-ordered subsets of $\mathbb{Q}_+$ (the positive rationals).  Put a metric on $M$ as follows: given distinct $X,Y\in M$, let $q$ be the least element of the symmetric difference $X\mathbin{\triangle} Y$.  Define $d(X,Y)=1/q$.

It is easy to verify that this is a metric (in fact, it is an ultrametric), and it obviously satisfies (1).  It satisfies (2) since for any $X\in M$ and any $q\in\mathbb{Q}_+$, the set $Y=X\mathbin{\triangle}\{1/q\}$ is an element of $M$ and satisfies $d(X,Y)=q$.

Finally, I claim $M$ is complete.  Indeed, if $(X_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $M$, that means that for each $q\in\mathbb{Q}_+$, the sets $X_n\cap(0,q]$ eventually stabilize.  Let $$X=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}_+:q\in X_n\text{ for all sufficiently large }n\}.$$  I claim that $X\in M$ and $(X_n)$ converges to $X$.

First, to prove $X$ is well-ordered and hence in $M$, let $A\subseteq X$ be any nonempty subset; say $q\in A$.  Choose $N$ such that $X_n\cap(0,q]$ is constant for $n\geq N$.  We then have that $X\cap (0,q]$ is equal to that constant value of $X_n\cap(0,q]$.  In particular, $X\cap(0,q]$ is well-ordered since each $X_n$ is.  Thus $A\cap(0,q]$ has a least element, which is then also the least element of $A$.

To prove $(X_n)$ converges to $X$, just note that if $X_n\cap(0,q]$ is constant for $n\geq N$, then $d(X_n,X)<1/q$ for all $n\geq N$.

More generally, this construction works with $\mathbb{Q}_+$ replaced by any subset $Q\subseteq\mathbb{R}_+$, and gives a complete metric space whose metric takes values in the set $\{0\}\cup\{1/q:q\in Q\}$ and satisfies the analogue of your condition (2).

(This example is closely related to [Hahn series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_series).  Indeed, my $M$ is really just the Hahn series field $\mathbb{F}_2[[\mathbb{Q}_+]]$ with a slightly nonstandard version of the metric induced by the valuation.)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!